# Android actionbar icons too big in "tabs-header"

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-icons

I have three tabs that should show up in the actionbar using fragments, the setup is like this:

```
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab buddyTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Buddys");
    ActionBar.Tab chatsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Chats");
    ActionBar.Tab schedularTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Schedular");
    buddyTab.setIcon(R.drawable.buddylistwhite);
    chatsTab.setIcon(R.drawable.chatswhite);
    schedularTab.setIcon(R.drawable.schedularwhite);

    buddysFragment = new BuddysFragment();
    chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
    schedularFragment = new SchedularFragment();

    buddyTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "buddys", buddysFragment));
    chatsTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "chats", chatsFragment));
    schedularTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "schedular", schedularFragment));

    actionbar.addTab(buddyTab);
    actionbar.addTab(chatsTab);
    actionbar.addTab(schedularTab);
```

Sadly the icons are shown fullsize (128px x 128px). When i was using the prior tabhost it "automatically" was scaled correctly, so that i got a clean look showing text and the icon in the header.
How can i make the actionbar behave similar, so showing up text and icon in a appropriate way? Or am i simply doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
sMau